# limit of $x_{n}=(-1)^{n}\sin(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have this sequence $x_{n}=(-1)^{n}\sin(\frac{1}{n})$

I have to chose from: a. $(x_n)$ is bounded and monotone. b. $(x_n)$ has the limit 0. c. $(x_n)$ is unbounded. d. $(x_n)$ has the limit 1.

I wrote that $(x_n)$ is positive when n=2k and negative when n=2k+1.I wrote $(x_n)$ like $\frac{sin\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$ the first part tends to 1 so the limit of $x_n$ is 0.

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2):

The limit is correct, but the justification is wrong. You simply have that

$$|x_n|\leq \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\underset{n\to 0}{\longrightarrow }0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence is absolutely convergent. So it must be convergent. For the limit it is easy to know it is 0. You can use squeeze thm.

$$-\sin(\frac1n)\leq x_n\leq \sin(\frac1n)$$

Both sides clearly converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_{2n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sin(\frac{1}{2n})=0$$

by the same
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_{2n+1}=0$$

thus
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_{2n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty} x_{2n+1}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=0$$

Comment: IMO this is a weak proof. The convergence requires that EVERY subsequence converge to the same limit-- in this case, of course it does. This proves two of them, not EVERY. I don't think this proof works unless enhanced. However much more direct methods work much more elegantly. Not about to start a quarrel, just saying.

Comment: @BookBookBook If both $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$ converge to the same limit , then $(x_n)$ goes to this limit.

Answer (score 0):

As $n \to \infty$ the sequence tends to $0$ (because $sin(1/n) \to 0$), though not monotonically (because $(-1)^{n}$ is alternating between -1 and 1).